# Resize of VBox as part of Scene JavaFX

Tags: java, kotlin, javafx, tornadofx, vbox

I'm new in Kotlin and TornadoFX, so I need to resize VBox as Rectangle on the code below.  Inside my VBox I also have other components like scroll pane or HBox so maybe it isn't very clear resizing my VBox.  But as I tested, this code below does exactly what I need but only for Rectangle, not VBox.  So How can I use this code for resizing VBox or what do I need to add for resizing it? Or maybe any tips for using frameworks JavaFX or TornadoFX to resize my VBox?

```
import javafx.event.EventHandler
import javafx.scene.Cursor
import javafx.scene.Node
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle

class DragResizeMod {
interface OnDragResizeEventListener {
    fun onDrag(node: Node?, x: Double, y: Double, h: Double, w: Double)
    fun onResize(node: Node?, x: Double, y: Double, h: Double, w: Double)
}

private val defaultListener: OnDragResizeEventListener = object: OnDragResizeEventListener {
    override fun onDrag(node: Node?, x: Double, y: Double, h: Double, w: Double) {

        setNodeSize(node, x, y, h, w)
    }

    override fun onResize(node: Node?, x: Double, y: Double, h: Double, w: Double) {

        setNodeSize(node, x, y, h, w)
    }

    fun setNodeSize(node: Node?, x: Double, y: Double, h: Double, w: Double) {
        node!!.layoutX = x
        node.layoutY = y
        if (node is Canvas) {
            node.width = w
            node.height = h
        } else if (node is Rectangle) {
            node.width = w
            node.height = h
        }

    }
}

enum class S {
    DEFAULT, DRAG, NW_RESIZE, SW_RESIZE, NE_RESIZE, SE_RESIZE, E_RESIZE, W_RESIZE, N_RESIZE, S_RESIZE
}

private var clickX = 0.0
private var clickY = 0.0
private var nodeX = 0.0
private var nodeY = 0.0
private var nodeH = 0.0
private var nodeW = 0.0

private var state = S.DEFAULT

private var node: Node? = null
private var listener: OnDragResizeEventListener? = defaultListener

private val MARGIN = 8
private val MIN_W = 30.0
private val MIN_H = 20.0

constructor(node: Node, listener: OnDragResizeEventListener?) {
    this.node = node
    if (listener != null) this.listener = listener
    makeResizable(node)
}

fun makeResizable(node: Node) {
    makeResizable(node, null)
}

fun makeResizable(node: Node, listener: OnDragResizeEventListener?) {
    node.onMousePressed = EventHandler { event -> mousePressed(event!!) }
    node.onMouseDragged = EventHandler { event -> mouseDragged(event!!) }
    node.onMouseMoved = EventHandler { event -> mouseOver(event!!) }
    node.onMouseReleased = EventHandler { event -> mouseReleased(event) }
}

protected fun mouseReleased(event: MouseEvent?) {
    node!!.cursor = Cursor.DEFAULT
    state = S.DEFAULT
}

protected fun mouseOver(event: MouseEvent) {
    val state = currentMouseState(event)
    val cursor = getCursorForState(state)
    node!!.cursor = cursor
}

private fun currentMouseState(event: MouseEvent): S {
    var state = S.DEFAULT
    val left = isLeftResizeZone(event)
    val right = isRightResizeZone(event)
    val top = isTopResizeZone(event)
    val bottom = isBottomResizeZone(event)
    if (left && top) state = S.NW_RESIZE else if (left && bottom) state = S.SW_RESIZE else if (right && top) state =
        S.NE_RESIZE else if (right && bottom) state = S.SE_RESIZE else if (right) state =
        S.E_RESIZE else if (left) state = S.W_RESIZE else if (top) state = S.N_RESIZE else if (bottom) state =
        S.S_RESIZE else if (isInDragZone(event)) state = S.DRAG
    return state
}

private fun getCursorForState(state: S): Cursor {
    return when (state) {
        S.NW_RESIZE -> Cursor.NW_RESIZE
        S.SW_RESIZE -> Cursor.SW_RESIZE
        S.NE_RESIZE -> Cursor.NE_RESIZE
        S.SE_RESIZE -> Cursor.SE_RESIZE
        S.E_RESIZE -> Cursor.E_RESIZE
        S.W_RESIZE -> Cursor.W_RESIZE
        S.N_RESIZE -> Cursor.N_RESIZE
        S.S_RESIZE -> Cursor.S_RESIZE
        else -> Cursor.DEFAULT
    }
}

protected fun mouseDragged(event: MouseEvent) {
    if (listener != null) {
        val mouseX = parentX(event.x)
        val mouseY = parentY(event.y)
        if (state == S.DRAG) {
            listener!!.onDrag(node, mouseX - clickX, mouseY - clickY, nodeH, nodeW)
        } else if (state != S.DEFAULT) {
            
            var newX = nodeX
            var newY = nodeY
            var newH = nodeH
            var newW = nodeW

            
            if (state == S.E_RESIZE || state == S.NE_RESIZE || state == S.SE_RESIZE) {
                newW = mouseX - nodeX
            }
            
            if (state == S.W_RESIZE || state == S.NW_RESIZE || state == S.SW_RESIZE) {
                newX = mouseX
                newW = nodeW + nodeX - newX
            }

            
            if (state == S.S_RESIZE || state == S.SE_RESIZE || state == S.SW_RESIZE) {
                newH = mouseY - nodeY
            }
            
            if (state == S.N_RESIZE || state == S.NW_RESIZE || state == S.NE_RESIZE) {
                newY = mouseY
                newH = nodeH + nodeY - newY
            }

            
            if (newW < MIN_W) {
                if (state == S.W_RESIZE || state == S.NW_RESIZE || state == S.SW_RESIZE) newX = newX - MIN_W + newW
                newW = MIN_W
            }
            if (newH < MIN_H) {
                if (state == S.N_RESIZE || state == S.NW_RESIZE || state == S.NE_RESIZE) newY = newY + newH - MIN_H
                newH = MIN_H
            }
            listener!!.onResize(node, newX, newY, newH, newW)
        }
    }
}

protected fun mousePressed(event: MouseEvent) {
    state = if (isInResizeZone(event)) {
        setNewInitialEventCoordinates(event)
        currentMouseState(event)
    } else if (isInDragZone(event)) {
        setNewInitialEventCoordinates(event)
        S.DRAG
    } else {
        S.DEFAULT
    }
}

private fun setNewInitialEventCoordinates(event: MouseEvent) {
    nodeX = nodeX()
    nodeY = nodeY()
    nodeH = nodeH()
    nodeW = nodeW()
    clickX = event.x
    clickY = event.y
}

private fun isInResizeZone(event: MouseEvent): Boolean {
    return (isLeftResizeZone(event) || isRightResizeZone(event)
            || isBottomResizeZone(event) || isTopResizeZone(event))
}

private fun isInDragZone(event: MouseEvent): Boolean {
    val xPos = parentX(event.x)
    val yPos = parentY(event.y)
    val nodeX = nodeX() + MARGIN
    val nodeY = nodeY() + MARGIN
    val nodeX0 = nodeX() + nodeW() - MARGIN
    val nodeY0 = nodeY() + nodeH() - MARGIN
    return xPos > nodeX && xPos < nodeX0 && yPos > nodeY && yPos < nodeY0
}

private fun isLeftResizeZone(event: MouseEvent): Boolean {
    return intersect(0.0, event.x)
}

private fun isRightResizeZone(event: MouseEvent): Boolean {
    return intersect(nodeW(), event.x)
}

private fun isTopResizeZone(event: MouseEvent): Boolean {
    return intersect(0.0, event.y)
}

private fun isBottomResizeZone(event: MouseEvent): Boolean {
    return intersect(nodeH(), event.y)
}

private fun intersect(side: Double, point: Double): Boolean {
    return side + MARGIN > point && side - MARGIN < point
}

private fun parentX(localX: Double): Double {
    return nodeX() + localX
}

private fun parentY(localY: Double): Double {
    return nodeY() + localY
}

private fun nodeX(): Double {
    return node!!.boundsInParent.minX
}

private fun nodeY(): Double {
    return node!!.boundsInParent.minY
}

private fun nodeW(): Double {
    return node!!.boundsInParent.width
}

private fun nodeH(): Double {
    return node!!.boundsInParent.height
}
```

}

Comment: can't open the link of this  Java code. 404 error.

Comment: Oops, I had a copy and paste error in the original comment, I will replace the original comment with a new comment with the correct link because comments are not editable after 5 mins.

Comment: This looks like a kotlin clone of [this java code](https://github.com/varren/JavaFX-Resizable-Draggable-Node/blob/master/src/sample/DragResizeMod.java) from this [github project](https://github.com/varren/JavaFX-Resizable-Draggable-Node). You could try asking the code's author if you can contact them. You may receive more responses if you post a minimal reproducible example written in java that is complete and replicates the issue via copy and paste.